# Let $T$ be a tree of order $n \geq 4$, and let $e_1,e_2,e_3 \in E(\overline T)$. Show that $T+e_1+e_2+e_3$ is planar.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T$ be a tree of order $n \geq 4$, and let $e_1,e_2,e_3 \in E(\overline T)$. Show that $T+e_1+e_2+e_3$ is planar.

I know that for any tree $m=n-1$ and since $T$ has only one region, it's outer planar thus planar. Since $T$ is planar, there is no $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ in it. Can I say that there is no $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ in $T+e_1+e_2+e_3$ as well?

Comment: You can do that, but the annoying part is that you also have to show that there is no subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.  Though it should be feasible (I guess) to show that removing any 3 edges from such a subdivision still leaves a cycle, or disconnects the graph.

Comment: Is there a sign to tell if a a graph has subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ without keeping adding vertices into the graph and check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'annoying part' is not too hard with the proper approach.

I'll show that removing 3 edges from $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ leaves a cycle ($K_{3,3}$ may also get disconnected but that is irrelevant). From there you can probably finish the proof by yourself.

Just use the elementary result that a graph with $n$ vertices and at least $n$ edges must have a cycle.

$K_5$ has $\binom 52=10$ edges. 
Removing any three of them leaves a graph with 5 vertices and 7 edges, which must have a cycle.

$K_{3,3}$ has $3\times 3=9$ edges. 
Removing any three of them leaves a graph with 6 vertices and 6 edges, which must have a cycle.

Comment: Right, and each subdivision adds exactly one vertex and one edge, so it's not really annoying :)

Comment: Can I argue this by counting the cycle? By adding 3 edges into the tree, the new graph will have at most 6 cycles, but both $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ have more than 7 cycles, so the new graph can't have any of those as subdivision.

Comment: Yes, but you need to prove every part of your claim, i.e. you need to prove that $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ have more than 7 cycles and that adding 3 edges produces at most 6 cycles. That does not sound a lot easier than above approach.